# Date.style undefined but don't see why

Tags: javascript, html, validation

JavaScript rookie here, trying to understand why the first validation in the following code is not working. I am getting that `Date.style` is undefined but this is just a copy from the code I am using on the other fields and is working fine in all of them except for `validationDate(ymd)`.

```
function validateDate(ymd) {
    var ymd = document.getElementById('Date').value;
    var legalEntry = /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/;

    if (ymd.length == 0) {
        Date.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The date can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    } else if (!legalEntry.test(ymd)) {
        Date.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The date must be in format YYYY-MM-DD";
        return false;
    } else {
        Date.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

    <tr><td>Date (YYYY-MM-DD)*</td>
    <td><input type="text" onblur="validateDate()" name="Date" id="Date" size="10" maxlength="10"/></td>
```

Thanks

As requested here is the full code which is working for the other fields:

```
function validateForm() {
    return (validateRunnerId
        && validateEventId
        && validateDate
        && validateTime
        && validatePosition
        && validateCategoryId
        && validateAge
        && validatePB);
}


function validateRunnerId(ID) {
    var ID = document.getElementById('RunnerId').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d{1,5}?$/;

    if (ID.length == 0) {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The RunnerId can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ID)) {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The RunnerId must be a number from 1 to 99999";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateEventId(ID) {
    var ID = document.getElementById('EventId').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d{1,5}?$/;

    if (ID.length == 0) {
        EventId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The EventId can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ID)) {
        EventId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The EventId must be a number from 1 to 99999";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        EventId.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateDate(date) {
    var date = document.getElementById('Date').value;
    var legalEntry = /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/;

    if (date.length == 0) {
        Date.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The date can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(date)) {
        Date.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The date must be in format YYYY-MM-DD";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Date.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateTime(time) {
    var time = document.getElementById('Time').value;
    var legalEntry = /^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$;/

    if (time.length == 0) {
        Time.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The finish time can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(time)) {
        Time.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The finish time must be in format HH:MM:SS";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Time.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validatePosition(position) {
    var position = document.getElementById('Position').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d{1,5}?$/

    if (position.length == 0) {
        Position.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The position can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(position)) {
        Position.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The position must be a number from 1 to 99999";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Position.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateCategoryId(ID) {
    var ID = document.getElementById('CategoryId').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d\d?[0]?$/;

    if (ID.length == 0) {
        CategoryId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The CategoryId can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(ID)) {
        CategoryId.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The CategoryId must be a number from 1 to 100";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        RunnerId.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validateAge(age) {
    var age = document.getElementById('Age').value;
    var legalEntry = /^\d\d?\,?\d?\d?$/;

    if (age.length == 0) {
        Age.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The age grade can\'t be empty";
        return false;
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(age)) {
        Age.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The age grade must be decimal number of maximum 2 integers and 2 decimals";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        Age.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}

function validatePB(pb) {
    var pb = document.getElementById('PB').value;
    var legalEntry = /^(0|1)$/;

    if (pb.length == 0) {
        pb.value = "0";
    }

    else if (!legalEntry.test(pb)) {
        PB.style.background = 'Orange'; 
        error.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "The PB can only be 0 for false and 1 for true";
        return false;
        }

    else {
        PB.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to assign to the `Date` constructor (unless you have redefined it)? If you have redefined it, could you show the relevant code?

Comment: as ecplained above, I am a rookie on this. My code works for the other fields. Here is the rest of it:

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Your `date` variable and `Date` are not the same object.

Comment: I know, one is the variable, the other one id the id object in the html form...

Comment: No, you've got `Date.style.background` everywhere, and it should be `date.style.background`. In JS `Date` with a capital `D` is the constructor for [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). (Some browsers do let you use an element's id as if it was a variable in your JS, but this is not a good practice.)

Comment: changing it to date.stlye.background doesn't change the behaviour....

Comment: well, changing the variable name is still not helping...

I have updated the code

Comment: @nnnnnn finally got what you meant...I had to change the name given as id to the html field. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is depending on an old non-standard mechanism in browsers where element IDs get mapped to variables.  For example:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
    foo.innerHTML = 'Hi!';
</script>
```

The problem you're facing is that the internal logic looks kind of like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <script INTERNAL>
        if (window.foo == undefined) {
            window.foo = document.getElementById('foo');
        }
    </script>
</div>
<script>
    foo.innerHTML = 'Hi!';
</script>
```

The variable is only getting assigned when it doesn't already exist.  Your `Date` variable is never getting written because `window.Date` is an existing function.

You can see this in action at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fjkc/2/  If I have the elements, one named `Date`, one with the same name as a user-defined variable, and one with an unused name, only the one with an unused name gets mapped to a variable.

The simplest solution is to rename your "Date" element to something else like "DateField", but you've seen that this is very brittle.  Your best solution is to define a variable using `document.getElementById`.  You could even define it as `Date` inside a function scope without breaking anything external:

```
function validateDate(date) {
    var Date = document.getElementById('Date');
    ...
}

var foobar = new Date(); // <-- still works.
```